# Laravel Regex:IntegerX

Tags: php

I am trying to create a regex :

```
^([0-9])(X)$
```

But my regex can be 1 or 2 or 3 digits and it cant be more than 3 digits and less than 1. How can i do ?

Here some samples :

> 1X     - OK
>
> 10X    - OK
>
> 20X    - OK
>
> A2Xa - NO
>
> 100X - OK
>
> 1000X - NO

Comment: tried `^([0-9]+)(X)$` or just specify the number of occurences, `^([0-9]{1,3})(X)$` - this will catch `100X` but wont match `1000X`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set length constraint with `{<min>,<max>}`. Try with:

```
^([0-9]{1,3})(X)$
```

Here's working example:

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/k7O